# How to make a dynamic array of Sequences?

Tags: c++

This is what I have researched and told how to make the dynamic array :

Sequence* seqArray  = new Sequence [size];

However whenever I try to make this array it just calls the constructor for the Sequence instead of making the array.

Is the syntax wrong or is there a fundamental error in my understanding of how these arrays work?

Comment: *This is what I have researched and told how to make the dynamic array :* -- A "dynamic array" in C++ is spelled [std::vector<Sequence>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: What your code does is: at first it allocates storage for the `size` elements of the array and then initializes them using default initialization, or simply calling a constructor, in your case. Then it assigns a pointer to the first element of the newly created array to the `seqArray` variable.

Comment: I am aware that the best choice is to use a vector but I am supposed to make a dynamic array this way for my assignment. @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: Then you should mention this up front, about not able to use `std::vector`.  Second, the issue of the constructor being called -- the object has to be created.  Object creation requires construction.

Comment: *Is the syntax wrong* No. That is the correct syntax. *is there a fundamental error in my understanding of how these arrays work?* Yes. See the comment by @DeedeeMegadoodoo.

Answer (score 0):

You are dynamically creating multiple Sequence objects, so the constructor will be called.

If you want to make a resizable array, use `vector`.

If you just want to create an array with empty slots, use double pointer type:

```
Sequence ** seqArray = (Sequence **) malloc(size * sizeof(Sequence *));
```

and use `new` to create each element (or `vector<Sequence*>`).